# Node JS / Angular - Windows Active directory authentication with Node JS or Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, active-directory

I want to create a web application authentication with `node.js` that use windows active directory. I don't know how to recover the current session username and password, so I can directly connecting the current user session to my web application without re-enter the username and password.

Comment: You will need to use [Kerberos authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-authentication-overview) for this.

Comment: What about activedirectory package in node is that enough?

Comment: Probably not, that package will help you authenticate users if they've provided their usernames and passwords, but it won't help you much in using Kerberos to authenticate them. [express-kerberos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-kerberos) seems more useful for the job.

Comment: Yes they provide all those informations but the point of using the active directory authentication is writing the username password once

Comment: Use node-expose-sspi